# If I run setup:upgrade its giving below error

Tags: magento2, php, database

I have uploaded new module and trying to upgrade its giving below error.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE 434 WHERE `Non_unique` = 1' at line 1, query was: SHOW INDEXES FROM TABLE 434 WHERE `Non_unique` = 1
```

Its coming while setup upgrade.

Please help me someone to fix this.

Comment: add Installschema.php file for the new module that you've installed

Comment: I removed new module then also same error.